# Google Cloud Function Node.js Firebase Url

Tags: android, node.js, firebase, push-notification, google-cloud-functions

I have an Android app where I am able to send push notification from my device in http format, but now I want to write a node where I want the push notification to be scheduled on a particular date and time, Someone please help me I am stuck in this process from a long time

Here is my node;

```
 const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);


exports.sendNotification = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  const to = req.query.to;
  const title = req.query.title;
  const body = req.query.body;

  var payload;
  if (body != undefined && body !== '') {
    payload = {
      notification: {
        title: title,
        body: body
      }
    };
  } else {
    payload = {
      notification: {
        title: title
      }
    };
  }

  var options = {
    priority: "high",
    timeToLive: 60 * 60 * 24
  };

  if (to == 'all') {
    admin.messaging().sendToTopic(to, payload, options)
      .then(function (response) {
        res.send(200, 'ok');
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        res.send(200, 'failed');
      });
  } else {
    admin.messaging().sendToDevice(to, payload, options)
      .then(function (response) {
        res.send(200, 'ok');
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        res.send(200, 'failed');
      });
  }
});
```

Here I have URL when run the push notification is generated,

```
https://MyProjectName.cloudfunctions.net/sendNotification?to=all&title=hello&body=EnterBodyHere
```

Now, please help me in scheduling this push notification like this

localhost:8080:/schedulePush?day=17&month=10&hour=12&minute=22

Answer (score 0):

Cloud Functions currently does not have a built-in scheduling mechanism.  You'll need to make use of some other scheduler if you want to execute a function at a particular time.  There's a [blog post](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/03/how-to-schedule-cron-jobs-with-cloud.html) that was written about this, and [sample code](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/delete-unused-accounts-cron) that discusses this as well.

Comment: Well my friend said, You just need to create Node.js endpoint for scheduling push notifications. Date/time in URL query.........................


like , https://www.npmjs.com/package/cron
use this library, it has timezones and use them...........

i tried them but could not figure it out.

Comment: That package won't work with Cloud Functions because it's not running a single node.js instance that stays alive all the time.  Instead, multiple managed instances can and will come and go as the demand on your functions changes over time.

Comment: then do you have any suggestion on how to run a link on a scheduled date and time?

Comment: in my app lets say there is a order form,
where i place an order on 20th 5pm and when click on submit.
now i want a scheduled triggered notification on 20th 5pm

Comment: Did you read the blog post and sample code I linked to in my answer?